# jQuery, if radio-button is selected inside an iframe execute another script

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

A script to execute another jquery script (myscript), if a radio button inside an iframe is selected. The iframe shows a page from another domain website.

I want the code to recognize when a radio button is selected and execute myscript. Here is the code for radio button inside the iframe:

```
<div class="field field--has-radio-button" data-select-gateway="9465733">
    <input id="checkout_payment_gateway_9465733" autocomplete="off" type="radio" value="9465733" checked="checked" name="checkout[payment_gateway]">
    <label class="label--full-width" for="checkout_payment_gateway_9465733">
        Credit card
    </label>
    <ul class="field__icon payment-methods" data-brand-icons-for-gateway="9465733">
        <li data-payment-icon="bogus" class="payment-method bogus selected">Bogus
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#iframeID').load(function(){
 $('#iframeID').contents().find('#checkout_payment_gateway_9465733').bind('change',function() {        
        if($("#iframeID").contents().find('#checkout_payment_gateway_9465733').val() == some value you are looking for){
        //call your function based on radio value
        }
    });
});
```

Hopefully this addresses your question

Comment: Are you sure you did understand my question?

Comment: @ArensMyzyri,  You're right I misread the original question.  Let me edit my answer

Comment: @ArensMyzyri  I think I have a better understanding now.  Could you see if the editing answer is what you are looking for?